# Exception for listview adapter when listview is missing(Fragment)

Tags: android-listview, exception, nullpointerexception, simpleadapter

1) My Activity has many fragment, the fragments can switch to another(whole rootView change) by navigation drawer.

2) I have a listView in a fragment that update using simple adapter.

3) If I switch the fragment to another while listView is still loading.
-An error occur.

May i know how to make a exception for this??

I extend the simple adapter for listView

```
ListAdapter adapter = new ExtendedSimpleAdapter(
                                getActivity(), news_List,
                                R.layout.news_item, new String[]{"news", "datetime", "desc","day"},
                                new int[]{R.id.news, R.id.new_time, R.id.desc,R.id.day});
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

This is the custom adapter :

```
public class ExtendedSimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter{
      Context context2;

    public ExtendedSimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, String>> data, int     resource, String[] from, int[] to){
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        context2=context;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        // here you let SimpleAdapter built the view normally.
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // Then we get reference for Picasso
        ImageView img = (ImageView) v.getTag();
        TextView txt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.state);
        if(img == null){
            img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.new_pic);

            v.setTag(img);
        }
        // get the url from the data you passed to the `Map`
        String url =  ((Map<String, String>)getItem(position)).get("pic");
        String type =  ((Map<String, String>)getItem(position)).get("type");
        String state =  ((Map<String, String>)getItem(position)).get("state");
        if (type.equals("reward"))
        {
            txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if(url.equals("")){
            Picasso.with(context2).load(R.drawable.default).into(img);

        }
        else{
            Picasso.with(context2)
                    .load(url)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.default)
                    .resize(100, 100)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(img);
        }

        // return the view

        return v;
    }
}
```

The error message NullPointerException

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.werebits.chopinkmerchant, PID: 14486
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.<init>(SimpleAdapter.java:85)
            at com.werebits.chopinkmerchant.ExtendedSimpleAdapter.<init>(ExtendedSimpleAdapter.java:19)
            at com.werebits.chopinkmerchant.Home$PlaceholderFragment$4.onSuccess(Home.java:488)
            at com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler$1$1.run(JsonHttpResponseHandler.java:128)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5230)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:780)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:596)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is this means when i switch fragment when the listView is still loading, the adapter can't find the listview??

how to add exception for this???